# Evaluating Racket expression

Tags: racket

Given these definitions:

```
(define s 8)
(define p (/ s 2))
(define (f s p)
        (cond [(or (> s 0) p) 'yes] [(< s 0) 'no]))
```

I want to evaluate this expression:

```
(f 0 (and (< s p) (> s 2)))
```

So far I have:

```
       ⇒    (f 0 (and (< 8 p) (> s 2))) 
       ⇒    (f 0 (and (< 8 4) (> s 2))) 
       ⇒    (f 0 (and false (> s 2)))
       ⇒    (f 0 false)
```

How do I finish this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace this with the body of `f` (the `cond` expression) with the parameters replaced by their matching arguments.

Comment: the program is not accepting if i write 0 instead of cond

Comment: What makes you think you should replace `cond` with 0?

Comment: @ScottHunter: I think it's clear that kaminey doesn't understand your answer. I understand your hesitation to just give him/her the complete answer to his/her homework, but maybe you could make up a different function to demonstrate your "replace this with the body of `f`" procedure with?

Comment: @ruakh This question is definitely homework but it's behind a login so I can't post it here. The course also uses its own stepping rules that are slightly different from the rules used in DrRacket's stepper -- the assignment makes this abundantly clear.

Comment: In that case, it seems unlikely that Stack Overflow is going to be able to help.... can @kaminey characterize the nature of the nonstandard reduction rules?

Answer (score 0):

Racket sees that `f` is a procedure and evaluates it's arguments:

```
(f 0 (and (< s p) (> s 2))) ; ==>
(f 0 (and (< 8 4) (> 8 2))) ; ==>
(f 0 (and #f #t))           ; ==>
(f 0 #f)                    ; s=0, p=#f
```

Then the arguments is substituted for the variables in the body of `f`:

```
; ==>
(cond [(or (> 0 0) #f) 'yes]
      [(< 0 0) 'no])
```

since both `(or (> 0 0) #f)` and `(< 0 0)` are `#f` the result is the undefined value chosen by the implementation. In racket it's `#<void>`

```
; ==>
#<void>
```

This could have been avoided by always have a `else` term:

```
(define (f s p)
  (cond [(or (> s 0) p) 'yes] 
        [(< s 0) 'no]
        [else 'banana]))

(f 0 (and (< s p) (> s 2))) ; ==> banana
```